# SQL query to return percentage of rows where binary variable equals a value, by month

Tags: sql-server, date, group-by, ssms

I need to run a query that returns the % of rows where the Type column is equal to "Yes", grouped by month. My data looks similar to what is below

| id | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2013 | Yes |
| 2 | 1/2/2013 | No |
| 3 | 2/1/2013 | Yes |
| 4 | 2/2/2013 | Yes |

So, I'd want to return something like

| Month | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2013 | 0.5 |
| 2/2013 | 1 |

I tried this based on a previous answer, but since my 'Type' column isn't numeric it doesn't work.

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,Date) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH,Date) AS Month,
        SUM(CAST(Type AS INT)) AS Passes,
        COUNT(*) as Total,
        CAST(1.00*SUM(CAST(Type AS INT)) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5,2) AS PercentagePass
FROM table
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,Date), DATEPART(MONTH,Date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,Date), DATEPART(MONTH,Date)
```

After some searching around I'm a bit confused on how to best handle my 'Type' variable as a string. I know I can convert it to 1s and 0s, but feel that replacing a line or two from the code above would be more efficient. I just can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just having trouble with `Type`, just use a *case expression* or *inline if* such as:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,Date) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH,Date) AS Month,
        SUM(Iif(type='Yes',1,0)) AS Passes,
        COUNT(*) as Total,
        Cast(SUM(Iif(type='Yes',1.0,0)) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS PercentagePass
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,Date), DATEPART(MONTH,Date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,Date), DATEPART(MONTH,Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option ... you can use a simple average

**Example**

```
Select YearMonth = left(Date,7)
      ,Pct = avg( case when [Type]='Yes' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
 From YourTable
 Group By left(Date,7)
```

**Results**

```
YearMonth   Pct
2013-01     0.5
2013-02     1
```